# How to mock java.nio.file.Files.write() in JUnit5

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I have to write a `JUnit5` test case to cover the catch block in the following code. However, I'm unable to throw `IOException` due to which it never ends in the catch block.
I tried a couple of things but I can't successfully mock `Files.write(...)` to throw the required exception.
How to throw this exception?

Code to cover

```
private static final String pathString = "path";

public String createFile() {
  JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
  String file;
  json.put("key", value);
  try{
     Path streamJson = Files.write(Paths.get(pathString), json.toJSONString().getBytes());
     file = streamJson.toString();
     return file;
  } catch(IOException e){
       return null;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Use Mockito and its ability to mock static methods.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you cannot solve your issue with Junit5 alone. I don't know if libraries like [Powermock](https://github.com/powermock/powermock) could solve your problem.

If not, how about refactoring your code to use a class that wraps the code to write the file (like a FileHelper, FileSystem, FileRepository or something similar)?

This way you could mock that class to let the mock behave like you need to have it for your test case.

Answer (score 0):

there are at least two ways to get an IOException:

```
throw new IOException();
```

or

open your file system and make the file your trying to write to read only.